# what is the use of [ampersn] in scanf() in c language

Tags: c

why we use `& (ampersn)` sign in `scanf()` while storing value.

PS : I know it is used to store value of variable at proper address.

Is there any other proper reason?

Comment: Why do you thing the given reason is _improper_?

Comment: @SouravGhosh because check out the below answer it is the proper reason the referencing and dereferencing part it was not clear in the above reason.

Comment: Nothing was clear, anyway, just a suggestion: start reading some good book.

Comment: Please next time when asking a question, use the keywords from your title in Google with `site:stackoverflow.com` to find previous questions with excellent answers that exist on Stack Overflow. Your question will be met more positively if you can demonstrate that you've done your research.

Answer (score 3):

In C you can only pass arguments *by value*. That means as you pass an argument to a function, the value is *copied*.

C doesn't have pass by reference, but it can be emulated using pointers.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(int a)
{
    a = 123;  // Modify local copy
}

void f2(int *a)
{
    *a = 234;  // Modify value where a is pointing
}

int main(void)
{
    int a1 = 0, a2 = 0;

    f1(a1);
    f2(&a2);

    printf("a1 = %d, a2 = %d\n", a1, a2);
}
```

The above program would print

```
a1 = 0, a2 = 234
```

That's because when `f1` modifies the value of its argument, it only modifies its local copy. The original (the variable `a1` in the `main` function) is not modified.

The function `f2` on the other hand emulates pass by reference. When calling `f2` we pass a pointer to the variable `a2` by using the address-of operator `&`. Then the function can dereference that pointer to get where it is pointing (the variable `a2` in the `main` function) and modify it.

Because the `scanf` function needs to modify variables, you can not pass copies of their current values, you need to pass pointers to the variables like when calling `f2` in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

In `c` **all** function parameters are passed by value.

That means that a function cannot modify the parameters passed by the caller.

What it *can* do, other than making use of `return`, is to accept *pointer* types (to arrays or objects) as parameters, and modify those arrays or objects by *dereferencing* those pointers.

This is the approach used by `scanf`. `scanf` also makes use of `return` as well.